# String replace between symbols?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object like this :

```
myDataObject = {
    name : 'Nikola Tesla',
    birth : ['10 July 1856','10. Juli 1856'],
    nation : ['Serbian','Serbisch'],
    knownFor : ['Alternating current',' Zweiphasenwechselstrom']
}
```

And two string patterns like these :

```
var englishStr = '#name#, born #birth[1]# , #nation[1]# best known for his contributions to #knownFor[1]#';

var deutschStr = '#name#, geboren #birth[2]#, #nation[2]# Erfinder, der für seine Beiträge zur #knownFor[2]# bekannt';
```

Now I want to replace `#properties#` marked like this.

I could do it easily if there was no multilanguage indicator like [1] or [2] smth. similar to this :

```
$.each(myDataObject , function(n, v){
    englishStr = englishStr.replace('#'+ n +'#' , v )
});
```

So what can I do about the `#prop[i]#` ? Thank you

Comment: That is a strange way of doing translations. Most of time you have an object for one language and use that.

Comment: This was only a sample to explain my situation in a simple way.Actually it is more complex and I have to use this pattern. Some properties may not have alternatives like #name# as in the code.

Comment: There are a lot of existing libraries that can do what you want, for example the [moustache templating system](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js): `Mustache.render( '{{name}}, geboren am {{birth}}', { name: 'Nikola Tesla', birth: '10. Juli 1856' } )`. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would go from the string to the data object instead of looping through all the keys.

```
var myDataObject = {
    name : 'Nikola Tesla',
    birth : ['10 July 1856','10. Juli 1856'],
    nation : ['Serbian','Serbisch'],
    knownFor : ['Alternating current',' Zweiphasenwechselstrom']
};
var englishStr = "#name#, born #birth[1]# , #nation[1]# best known for his contributions to  #knownFor[1]#";




var re = /#([^\[#]+)\[?(\d+)?\]?#/;  //Looks for #STRING# or #STRING[NUMBER]#
var test;
while ( (test=re.exec(englishStr))!==null) {  //Keep looking for matches in the string
    var key = test[1];   //get the key to the object
    var index = test[2]; //get the index if there
    var item = myDataObject[key];  //get reference to the item in the object
    if (index!==undefined && item) {  //if we have an index, look up the value from array
        index = parseInt(index,10)-1;  //arrays are zero index, so need to subtract one
        item = item[index];  //get the string
    }
    englishStr = englishStr.replace(re, item || "N/A");  //make the replacement in the string with the data from the object
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try a slightly different approach here.  Instead of looping over the `myDataObject` blindly trying to replace values, first pull out the values that need replacing, then replace them with their values.

```
var regex = /#(.*?)(?:\[(\d*)])?#/g;
while(match = regex.exec(englishStr)){
    var matchStr = match[0];
    var data = myDataObject[match[1]];
    if(match[2] !== undefined){
        data = data[match[2] - 1];
    }

    englishStr = englishStr.replace(matchStr, data);
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/35jZM/

Answer (score 1):

see if this might help

```
$.each(myDataObject , function(n, v){

    if(typeof v == 'object'){
        $.each(v , function(index, value){
            englishStr = englishStr.replace('#'+ n +'[' + index + ']' + '#' , v[index-1]    );

        });
   }
englishStr = englishStr.replace('#'+ n +'#' , v )

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cLqM2/2/)

Comment: You probably want `v[index-1]` :-)

Answer (score 1):

There might be better solutions but I'd do something like this:

```
myDataObject = {
    name: 'Nikola Tesla',
    birth: ['10 July 1856', '10. Juli 1856'],
    nation: ['Serbian', 'Serbisch'],
    knownFor: ['Alternating current', ' Zweiphasenwechselstrom']
};

// English: 0, Deutsch: 1
var language = 0;

var str = "#name#, born #$birth# , #$nation# best known for his contributions to  #$knownFor#";

$.each(myDataObject, function (n, v) {
    str = str.replace('#' + n + '#', v);
    str = str.replace('#$' + n + '#', v[language]);
});

alert(str);
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGzwW/)

Answer (score 1):

You could also pass capture groups in a regex replace to a callback function: 
<sup>*(take note that if the arrays in your translation strings are indexed from `1` you'll have to add that to `$2`)*</sup>

```js
englishStr.replace(/#(.+?)(?:\[(\d+)\])?#/g, function($0, $1, $2){ 
    return $2 === undefined ? myDataObject[$1] : myDataObject[$1][$2];
});
```

[image: regex visualisation]

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/H988M/)